# typeorm using `LOCK TABLE` with `EntityManager` `TRANSACTION`

Tags: postgresql, typeorm

I am currently trying to fix a race condition I encountered with typeorm.
I got two systems doing a transaction nearly at the same time, which include a select and a conditional insert.

To fix the issue, and not retrying the transaction multiple times, I opted for using `LOCK` (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/explicit-locking.html)

I got two questions for this use case.

The first is, is locking the right approach to solve two system accessing the same table and doing a transaction on them?
Is there another way, for example asking postgre to queue them and do them one at a time?

The second question is, is there a better way of applying the lock then I do?
Especially, since it looks so inconvinient.
I would have expected something like `em.lockTable(TestCaseProcessorEntity)`

My code currently looks something like this:

```js
import {EntityManager} from "typeorm";

// importing TestCaseProcessorEntity etc.

class TestCaseRegister {
  entityManager: EntityManager;
  logger: Logger;

  async registerProcessor(testCaseProcessorEntity: TestCaseProcessorEntity) {
    await this.entityManager.transaction(async em => {
      const TestCaseProcessorTableName = em.getRepository(TestCaseProcessorEntity).metadata.tableName;

      this.logger.log('Trying to get the lock for ' + TestCaseProcessorTableName);
      await em.query('LOCK TABLE ' + TestCaseProcessorTableName);
      this.logger.log('Acquired the lock for the table ' + TestCaseProcessorTableName);

      // would love to call:
      // await em.lockTable(TestCaseProcessorEntity)

      const found = await em.findOne(TestCaseProcessorEntity, {
        where: {id: testCaseProcessorEntity.id},
        select: {id: true, name: true, parameters: {id: true}},
        relations: {parameters: true}
      });

      this.logger.log((found ? 'found' : 'did not find') + ' the test case processor entity');

      if (found) {
        // Doing additional logic
      } else {
        await em.insert(TestCaseProcessorEntity, testCaseProcessorEntity);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: very bad decision. I don't understand at all what you need two queries for instead of a simple `insert from select`

Comment: @mrmcwolf there are two reasons, the first is that I can't insert the entity if it already exists and the second is that I have different logic depending on if it exists.

Comment: Well, if you cannot duplicate an object, use the `on conflict` do nothing (or do update) clause. If the success of the `insert` will lead to logical logic, check the return value (affected rows) to determine whether a new object has been added or not, but in no case do not lock the table unless you know exactly what you are doing and why.

Comment: @mrmcwolf sorry, maybe I was not clear, there are additional queries, after the entity was found (or not) so I need to be able to ensure that those queries run as one.

Comment: without a clearly stated problem you cannot get an answer. queries executed "as one" are run in a transaction (the database takes care of optimal locks, usually at the row level).

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using isolation level.

Comment: Please elaborate how to do that.